# Knowing the coordinates of all the tiles that make up a shape in a grid, is there a way to find the tiles along the perimeter of the shape?

Tags: geometry

I'm not exactly sure how to word this, which may be why I haven't been able to find an answer. But given the coordinates of all the "tiles" that make up a shape, is there an algorithmic way to find the tiles that run along the outside of this shape?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smGvp.png)

The dark blue squares are the shape (Coordinates: (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2)). The light blue squares are the perimeter tiles.

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovpGP.png)

A triangle this time, using the second interpretation of what "perimeter" means. Is it possible to find an algorithm that achieves this for any shape?

Any help is appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction or telling me a way to do something similar.

Comment: Do you mean that you are given the pixels (considered, as I understand as squares = tiles instead of points) of a shape, and you are looking for the description of a path through the "bordering pixels" of the given shape, like "NNWNWWS..."(N=north, W=west, etc.) ? Please, provide a figure.

Comment: Yes, given pixels. Looking for not a path, but the coordinates of the "bordering pixels"

Comment: So in the first example the results would be (in no particular order):
(3,0)
(4,0)
(2,1)
(2,2)
(5,1)
(5,2)
(3,3)
(4,3)

Comment: Suppress the tag "graph theory"

Comment: Sorry, I had to put a tag and I wasn't sure what it really fit under.